# How can I define $\sigma$-field for random variable inside polygon

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $W = (X, Y)$ be a r.v. uniformly distributed in a rectangle $R = \{(x,y) \; | \; \alpha_1 \leq x \leq \alpha_2, \beta_1 \leq y \leq \beta_2\}$ bounding the polygon $P$, and  $Q = \{(x,y) \; | \; a_1 \leq x \leq a_2, b_1 \leq y \leq b_2\}$ is an arbitrary square contained in $P$ then

\begin{equation}
P((X,Y) \in Q \; | \; (X,Y) \in P) = \frac{P((X,Y) \in Q)}{P((X,Y) \in P)} = \frac{area(Q)/area(R)}{area(P)/area(R)} = \frac{area(Q)}{area(P)}.
\label{eq:distribuicao_poligono1}
\end{equation}

Let $(\Omega, \mathbb{A}, P)$ be an arbitrary probability space, and let $Z = (X,Y)$ be a real-valued function on $\Omega$; $Z$ is uniformly distributed in polygon defined by

\begin{equation*}
F_{X, Y}(x, y)  = 
\begin{cases}
0, & x < a_1 \; or \; y < b_1, \\
\frac{(x - a_{2})(y - b_{2})}{A},  & \; if \; a_1 \leq x \leq a_2, and \; b_1 \leq y \leq b_1, \\
            1,  & \textrm{otherwise}. 
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}

How can I define the $\sigma$-field $\mathbb{A}$? And, how can I prove that $\mathbb{A}$ is a $\sigma$-field?

Comment: Why do you use the word polygon instead of rectangle?

Comment: Could you be more clearer? I'd like to find the $\sigma$-field to convex polygon.

Comment: Yes. How to show the sigma algebra to convex polygon? I found this example:

http://clux.x-pec.com/files/mathstuff/3rdyear/ST213%20-%20Mathematics%20of%20Random%20Events/hw4s.pdf